# Actions On Google account linking success is inconsistent in Google Home app

Tags: actions-on-google

Now that my Google Assistant service is approved and deployed for use with Google Home, I am seeing inconsistent behavior from the Google Home app WRT account linking.

There are 2 places you can do account linking for a service in the Google Home app:

1. When you navigate in the menu to 'More Settings', then 'Services', then pick the Service that you want, then scroll down and hit 'Link Account'. This works successfully some of the time. When it does, I can then invoke my service and verify that account linking is complete.
2. After saying 'OK Google, talk to XYZ', (where XYZ is your service name) the google assistant responds with "It looks like your XYZ account is not linked yet. You can link XYZ to your google account from the google home app". Then when you go to the Google Home app you see a new blue card that says 'Link to XYZ'. When you click 'link', it will sometimes successfully link, and many times an error 400 comes up: "Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.".

I haven't been able to conclusively determine why it works some of the time but fails many times as well. I did find in my latest round of testing that if I removed all other users from the Google Home app other than the specific user account that I was working with, I could get it to successfully link after multiple attempts. With this inconsistent behavior, it doesn't seem like the problem is on my side with the account linking process I put together per [these docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/identity/account-linking), but I don't know.

Has anyone else experienced similar account linking issues? If so did you find the root cause and resolve?

Comment: You can reach out to the actions support if you have a way to reproduce the issue: https://developers.google.com/actions/support/

Comment: W/further testing these issues with account linking are specific to the iphone app. It works well when testing with the browser / actions console, & also with the Google Home app for Android. Feedback from actions on google support is that the problem is that google sign in flow is implemented in separate browser tab (window). On iphone you can't open 2 windows in SfariViewController, thus they are re-writing address of the first page and can’t finish sign in flow. This is known issue and they are not planning to change this. The solution is to implement signin flow all in one browser window.

Comment: I've asked a separate question about this now given the further clarification on the problem statement - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44311663/actions-on-google-account-linking-on-iphone